# How to get only changed value on Firebase Database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to get only changed value on Firebase Database? Because every time I changed a value on `dir`, ex:

```
/ some_user
 ~ id
 ~ name
 / data
   ~ order_id
   ~ order_name <<= Changed in here
```

But when I get the changed data, I get all the tree structure and not only changed data `order_name`. So I just wanted it to return something like this:

```
/ some_user
     / data
       ~ order_name <<= Specific changed data
```

So I can identify what is the exact `key` data that has changed. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attach the listener to the order_name reference.

```
var user = "Alan";
var ref = firebase.database().ref(user + "/data/order_name");

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```